# Use .net to automate Google Chrome Print to PDF feature

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, pdf

I'm creating a small .Net application which processes some XML data, uses XSLT to transform the XML into HTML.

Google Chrome has a fantastic feature under it's Print options to Save to PDF. I can view my HTML file and save it as a paged PDF document.

I want to programatically, from my .Net app, use Google Chrome for it's PDF feature and automatically produce the PDF from the transformed XML?

How can I do this with my .Net code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like overkill. I would write you a little viewer to view the result HTML (using Internet Explorer API, or WebKit). Then API to the PDFCreator COM library to convert it to a PDF with a click of a button...

http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdfcreator/trunk/COM/Samples/Dot%20Net/VS2005/C%23/Sample1/Form1.cs?revision=1276&view=markup

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Good luck!